# Twitter bot to automatically accept follower request

Tags: python, twitter

I have a list of poeple I want to give them access to my restricted twitter account, is it possible to create a bot to accept the requests automatically rather than me manually accepting them in twitter.

Basically I update the list and the bot verifies if that particular user has sent me a request if so it accepts the request on behalf of me automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Twitter API feature for accepting follow requests - this is only available in the Twitter UI itself.